# Proof for determining Fourier coefficients

Tags: continuous-signals, fourier-series, self-study, proof

While determining Fourier coefficients we have this equation
$$\int^{T}_{0} x(t) e^{-jn\omega_0t} dt = \sum^{+\infty}_{k\ =\ -\infty} a_k [\int^{T}_{0} e^{j(k-n)\omega_0t}dt]$$

I want to ask that how can we get final equation of $a_n$ as:
$$a_n= 1/T \int^{T}_{0} x(t)e^{-jn\omega_0t}dt$$  from the above equation.
please any one help to explain this

Comment: [This answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22714/change-of-discrete-summation-to-definite-integral/22717#22717) to a related question also answers your question.

Comment: @MattL. while solving the integral part in equation 2 how $sin$ will be $\ 0 \ \forall k$ as we are solving integral for $T$, there is no $k$ in the integral

Comment: @MattL. can you please answer this [question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26493/confusion-in-ct-fourier-transform-proof/26501#26501)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the periodic signal $x(t)$ with fundamental period $T=1/F_0$, proceeding from where you are:

$$
\Rightarrow \sum^{+\infty}_{k\ =\ -\infty} a_k \left[\int^{T}_{0} e^{j(k-n)\omega_0t}dt\right] = \sum^{+\infty}_{k\ =\ -\infty} a_k \left[\frac{e^{j(k-n)\omega_0t}}{j(k-n)\omega_0}\right]^{T}_{0}
$$

1. For $k \neq n$ you got $0$ (you can prove that)
2. And for $k=n$ you see that $\int^{T}_{0}dt = T$

You therefore have:

$$\int^{T}_{0} x(t)e^{-jn\omega_0t} dt= a_kT = a_nT$$

You can proceed from there.

**EDIT:**

- We do not assume the existence of the two possible solutions. The right-hand side of the equation evaluates to that. It can be written in compact form using the unit impulse which has two distinct values depending on the index. (see [the Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#Properties) in digital signal processing). Think $\delta_{kn}$.
- We still need the summation, but we can start with the integral. It's only that the integral is zero for all values of $k$ except at $k=n$ where it is $T$. So you remain with one term in your summation.

All in all, your initial equation equals: $\displaystyle \sum^{+\infty}_{k\ =\ -\infty} a_kT\delta_{kn}$

Comment: after the solving the integral, we assume two possible solution to solve the summation. 1) $k\neq n$ and 2) $k=n$... please tell me is it correct what I understand?
Second thing I want to know is when we these two conditions then we don't need to summation?

Comment: @AadnanFarooqA I have edited the answer.

Comment: @AadnanFarooqA , any tick for the answer ?